# Oracle order by query very slow

Tags: oracle10g, sql-order-by

I am facing a problem when doing order by on a table.

My select query is working fine, but when i do order by (even on the primary key) it just goes on and on with no results. Finally i need to kill the session. The table has20K records.
Any suggestion for the this? 
Query is as:

```
SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY ID;
```

I do not about know about the query plan as i am new to oracle

Comment: To start with, can you post the query and the query plan?  How long does the query run before you kill it?  How many rows does the query return?

Comment: @Justin Cave: SQL Developer just shows loading icon even after 20mins. so i need to kill with option left

Comment: OK.  Are you editing your question to add the query and query plan?  What about the number of rows that are returned?

Comment: The Select query returns 20K records in some msec

Comment: Generating query plans is covered in the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm#16889  The simplest option is to do an `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ID;`  and then run the query against the `PLAN_TABLE` that is in the "Displaying the PLAN_TABLE Output" section in that document.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the unordered query, Is SQL Developer retrieving and displaying 20K rows, or just the fisrt 50?  Your comparison might not be fair.
2. What is the size of those 20K rows: `select bytes/1024/1024 MB from user_segments where segment_name = 'USERS';`  I've seen many cases where a few megabytes of data use many gigabytes of storage.  Maybe the data was very large before and somebody just deleted it (this doesn't remove the space).  Or maybe somebody inserted those rows 1 at a time with an APPEND hint, and each row is taking an entire block.
3. Your query might be waiting for more temp tablespace for sorting, look at DBA_RESUMABLE.